# Facebook API fetching user's first name

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to write a simple function which returns the current FB user first name.

I've been getting some odd responses so I added some bits to track down where the issue is.

```
  function firstName(){
    var userName="Default Name";

    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured fetching first name');
        userName="Name Error";
      } else {
        userName=response.first_name;
        console.log("TestPoint1: " + userName);
      }
    });
    console.log("Test Point2: " + userName);
    return userName;
  }
```

But if I call it using console.log("testCall: " + firstName); I get the following response in this order:-

```
Test Point2: Default Name
TestCall: Default Name
TestPoint1: Pete
```

So the function appears returning before the FB api call has finished.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming :)

The callback of the API call will get called asynchronously, so Test Point 2 will get called immediately after FB.api, but the function with the response will get called later.

Correct solution (you can´t work with "return"):

```js
function firstName(callback){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            callback('Name Error');
        } else {
            callback(response.first_name);
        }
    });
}
firstName(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

You can also use "Promises", but it´s not necessary in that case.

Comment: i´ve included a solution

Comment: Thanks Luschn, that works. I know need to go away, bash my head against the wall, make a strong cup of coffee then work out all that asychronous thingy!